# AppendRow() Limited Rows

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

How can I save data from a form only up to line 15? (as in the picture)?

```
function addNovaLinha(dadosLinha) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ws = ss.getSheetByName("resultados");
  const dataAtual = new Date();
  var limite = ss.getLastRow();

  ws.appendRow([dadosLinha.item, dadosLinha.qtd, dataAtual]);

  return true;  
}
```

[image: view image of sheet]

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a condition that checks if the last row has already reached `15`.

```
function addNovaLinha(dadosLinha) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ws = ss.getSheetByName("resultados");
  const dataAtual = new Date();
  var limite = ss.getLastRow();

  // append row and return true ONLY IF last row is less than 15 
  if(limite < 15) {
    ws.appendRow([dadosLinha.item, dadosLinha.qtd, dataAtual]);
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: hi @producaosantadica, if we answered your question, please click the accept button.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: so... I couldn't find it :/

Comment: Hi @producaosantadica, it is the check button on the left side of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

thankful for help. I managed to solve. with the response from